# How to run a TCP/IP game on a cluster

Tags: bash, shell, tcp, cluster-computing, sungridengine

I wrote a TCP/IP game that involves one server and two clients who then play the game, write some statistics about it and close. (It's two AIs playing a game)

I wrote a shell script that opens those three child scripts. However, currently no statistics are being written. Since sometimes the setup stage (clients connect to server) works and sometimes not even that, I assume that those children are wrongly distributed over the cores and can't communicate with the server. (?)

How would I generally solve this problem? Perhaps not with tmux? Running SGE, version 6.2u3beta.

Here's my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script is supposed to take a json problem instance (name is problemNNNNN.json)
# Then open server with -i problem$SGE_TASK_ID.json -o -p open-port,
# then open two clients with -p open-port.

#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -m n
#$ -l h_vmem=4G
## Tasks
#$ -t 1-1
#$ -cwd

problem_file=problem$SGE_TASK_ID.json

function find_open_port(){
    # Ports between 49152 - 65535 are usually unused.
    port=$(shuf -i '49152-65535' -n '1')

    # Then check if port is open
    if lsof -Pi :$port -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ; then
        find_open_port
    else
        # There is no service currently running on this port
        return $port
    fi
}

find_open_port

tmux new-session -d -s '$SGE_TASK_ID' "python server.py -p $port -i $problem_file"
sleep 1
tmux split-window -v -t '$SGE_TASK_ID' "python client.py -p $port"
sleep 1
tmux split-window -h -t '$SGE_TASK_ID' "python client.py -p $port"

exit
```

Comment: unless `$SGE_TASK_ID` has a value when you use it in `problem_file=problem$SGE_TASK_ID.json`, the assignment will be `problem_file=problem.json` . (i.e., $STE_TASK_ID is a variable with no value). Not certain that is causing your current problem, but it can't help. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but that part works fine. I actually have some echos in the code that I omitted for clarity here which show that $SGE_TASK_ID has the correct value. (problem.json also exists, so even that should work)